# Upgrade sql server in place on your team foundation server

Tags: sql-server, tfs

Is it possible to do an in place upgrade of you SQL server edition, (for example upgrade 2012 Express to Standard), when it is running and used by a team foundation server 2015 instance? Will this need extra configuration or will we need to detach/attach the team project collections first?

I can't find any information about how to do this. It is only stated how to upgrade the team foundation server itself, or that it is no problem to do edition upgrades of sql server, but not the combination of the two.

Comment: That's not *upgrading*. Express always runs side-by-side with full editions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**

You can:

1. Use the `TFSServiceControl quiesce` command to turn off your servers services.
2. Upgrade SQL Server in place following SQL Servers Instructions
3. Use the `TFSServiceControl unquiesce` command to turn on your servers services.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfsservicecontrol-cmd

Answer (score -3):

As far as I can remember:

### No.

1. You will need to detach your collection.
2. **Make sure the SQL Server version is supported by your TFS Version**